# Sequelize findOrCreate falling back to catch if data is found

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

FindOrCreate is suppose to either `find` or `create` based on the arguments you give it.

So I'm wondering why it's falling back to the `catch` promise when `data (a user)` is found, when it should just return the `data` that was found to the `.spread` function instead of trying to `insert` the data that already exists?!.

As you can see below if there is a user found or created it's going to run the same function regardless. All that function is doing is creating an `auth token` for the particular user. But for some reason it's going straight into the `catch` promise!?

```
User.findOrCreate({
    where: {
        userId: details.userId,
    },  
    defaults: {
        name: details.name,
        email: details.email,
    },
    attributes: ['userId', 'name', 'email', 'profilePic'],
    }).spread(function (new_user, created) {
        console.log("\n\nNew user was created T or F: ", created);

       // Create the token and then pass it back to our callback along with the user details
        user.createTokenForUser(new_user.userId, function(token) {
            cb(token, new_user);
        });
}).catch(function (err) {
    // For some reason I'm running...?!??!?!?!?!
    console.log("\n\n", err);
});
```

Comment: It would help if you pasted the actual error : `console.log("\n\n", err);`

Answer (score 1):

Did you try removing the trailing comma in the where statement?  Its just hitting an error and that looks like a culprit :)

```
where: {
        userId: details.userId,
    }
```

to

```
where: {
        userId: details.userId
    }
```