# Sequelize findOrCreate() -- .catch() block executed after spread() during no error

Tags: javascript, node.js, sequelize.js

My error is similar to this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36212942/sequelize-findorcreate-falling-back-to-catch-if-data-is-found?rq=1):

Using sequelize.js as an ORM handler.
queryCondition variable value: {where: {$or: [{username:user.username},{email:user.email}]},defaults:user}

Problem: After successfully saving a user instance to the database, the `spread()` is called as recommended after invoking `findOrCreate()`. The function block in `spread()` is invoked, then immediately after the `.catch()` block is invoked. No clue why this is happening. Can someone please help?

```
 model.User.findOrCreate(queryCondition).spread(function(user, created){
    callback && callback(user, created);
 }).catch(function(error){
     callback && callback(null, null, error);
 });
```

Comment: can You put in Your question the queryCondition variable?

Comment: {where: {$or: [{username:user.username}, {email:user.email}]},defaults:user}

Comment: That sounds like your `callback` did throw an exception. What is the `error`?

Comment: For cases such as this, you'll want to use the [`then(onFulfilled, onRejected)` pattern](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572) instead of `.then(…).catch(…)`. Or, given Sequelize uses Bluebird, have a look at [`asCallback`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/ascallback.html) (which does use node callback conventions though, not your custom parameter order).

Comment: There's no error. Data inserts successfully, but the .catch() block executes immediately after

Answer (score 4):

Found the answer:
Sequelize uses Bluebird.js as it's promise library (check out the package.json file). The [documentation](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/spread.html) explains the spread() method, which is recommended to use in sequelize 3.0 (see [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19003148/get-findorcreate-error)). A section in this document states that spread() invokes all().then(..) under the covers. Therefore, the following change solved my problem using Node.js:

`model.User.findOrCreate(queryCondition)
    .all().then(function(result, isCreated){
       callback && callback(null, result, isCreated);
    },
    function(error) {
       callback && callback(error);
    });`

Properly resolved promises do not fall into the error block, and actual database errors are caught in the error block. Finally, for those who assumed the error was due to the callback arguments, note that I simply reordered the callback arguments given num8er's suggestion below. :) Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: You're calling `callback` with three arguments now, instead of two like you did in your original question. My guess is that _that_ actually solved your problem, and not the rewrite to `.all().then()`. In your initial code, the callback most likely threw an exception (like @Bergi suggested) because it thought that an error had occurred, and that's the reason the `catch` triggered (I assume the callback does `if (err) throw err` or something similar).

Comment: I switched the argument order of my callback() given num8er's suggestion below to match convention...Switching parameters was not the cause of my error.

Comment: came here very lately,I checked package.json and it look like they are no longer using it, my sequenlize version is 6.6.5. maybe someone can confirm that?

Answer (score 2):

If it's invoking `.catch` block so it seems to have some issue.

Try to debug it and see the reason:

```
 model.User.findOrCreate(queryCondition).spread(function(user, created){
   callback && callback(user, created);
 }).catch(function(error){
   console.error(queryCondition, error); // add this and check the output
   callback && callback(null, null, error);
 });
```

also I saw that Your queryCondition variable is also ok.

```
{
  where:{$or: [{username:user.username},{email:user.email}]},
  defaults:user
}
```

so let's try this annotation:

```
{
  where:{$or: [{username: {$eq: user.username}},{email: {$eq: user.email}}]},
  defaults:user
}
```

read this: http://docs.sequelizejs.com/en/latest/docs/querying/#where

and if with another annotation it will not work properly so I can recommend You to check Your table columns for `null`, `not null` fields and compare it with `user` object to see if there is missing field in `user` object.

after reading Bergi's comment I'll also recommend You to try to do it like this:

```
 model.User
   .findOrCreate(queryCondition)
   .then(
     function(result, isCreated){
       callback && callback(result, isCreated);
     },
     function(error) {
       callback && callback(null, null, error);
     });
```

In case of `spread` method I think it does not throw exception to be catchable, so in  this case:

```
model.User
  .findOrCreate(queryCondition)
  .spread(function(result, isCreated){
    if(!result) {
      return callback && callback('Cannot create user');
    }
    callback && callback(null, result, isCreated);
  });
```

P.S. Usually in most of packages it's convention to return error as first argument of callback. So I can only guess that problem happens not in Your code example, it happens somewhere outside that waits for callback.

So try to modify callback like this:

```
callback(user, created);  =>  callback(null, user, created);

callback(null, null, error);  =>  callback(error);
```

Comment: Thanks for the ordering advice. I'll be sure to refactor...I also added the query condition JSON variable.

Comment: @jried I've updated my answer, please check Your table columns for constraints about required fields, I can guess that there is some not null fields that are not in Your user object

Comment: Tried two things: 
1. Adding a 3rd parameter .spread(function(error, user, created) ... Then printed the variable contents: There are only two variables returned from spread.

2. Removed the .catch() statement, this causes an exception if there actually is an error inserting data

Essentially, findOrCreate successfully inserts data, and I get the object back ... For some reason .catch() is still called immediately after successful resolve.

Comment: @jried I did not ment to change spread arguments )))  again can You do console.log(error) inside catch block?

Comment: @jried I've updated my answer and added Bergi's proposition, try it.

Comment: Hi, .then() does work, but it doesn't catch the 2nd variable (isCreated). Other posts say to use .spread() instead....I also did print the arguments and verified that I get the user object back (json object) but loose the "isCreated" variable. 

To answer your question about printing the output using spread() and .catch(). The variable queryCondition is correct. It creates the correct SQL statement and inserts correctly...The problem is the .catch() gets called still with "{}" as it's output.

Comment: Ok. Use spread without catch and only way to check that it did not executed is just check if(!result){}